# Why does pausing this Youtube video cause a popping sound?

Tags: youtube, glitch

When I do anything to interrupt this video's audio -- play/pause, mute/unmute , etc. -- I hear a popping sound. This doesn't happen with any other video I've seen.

Device info: OSX 10.12.6, Chrome 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit). The same thing is happening on my iPhone in the Youtube app.

What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is happening here on my laptop also. Without downloading the video and analysing the audio, it's most likely to be an issue with DC bias in the audio stream. This can be removed by re-encoding the audio with a high-pass filter set at a very low frequency (20Hz). You can also remove it by using a filter in the output stream of your audio interface. Trickier on a phone, but do-able on a laptop.